# How to set absolute reference in G-Sheets using Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to fill multiple columns with VLOOKUP formulas (requested by the user) in about 600 rows, but the script is taking too long (4-5 minutes). I'd like to speed things up by inserting the formula in the first row, locking the VLOOKUP range with absolute reference, and then copying the formula down the range. However, I can't find a GAS method that sets absolute reference (e.g. A1:A100 becomes $A$1:$A$100)

I've dug through Google's Developer hub, and I found some methods like isEndColumnBounded() that return a boolean. Though, I can't find anything that allows me to set absolute reference.

For now, I fill a vlookup formula with an incremental search ID and a static range into a two-dimensional array, and then set the range values to the array values. This is required for two-columns, and they take about 2 minutes each... way too long for only populating some 600 rows.

```
function myFunction()
  var idCol = 
    compSht.createTextFinder("ID")
    .matchEntireCell(true).findNext().getColumn();
    var vIndex = getVIndex(arcSht);
    var aEquation = [];  

  for(i=0;i<compSht.getLastRow()-1;i++) {
    aEquation[i] = new Array;    

    aEquation[i][0] =
      "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(" + compSht.getRange(i+2, idCol).getA1Notation() 
      + ",'" + arcStr + " Submission'!" + vIndex[2] + "," + vIndex[0] + 
      ',false), "No Data")';
  }
  compSht.getRange(2, hcCol, lRow-1).setValues(aEquation);
}

function getVIndex(sheet) {
  var idCol = 
    sheet.createTextFinder("ID").matchEntireCell(true);
    .findNext().getColumn();
  var hcCol = sheet.createTextFinder("Total HC").findNext().getColumn();
  var tcCol = sheet.createTextFinder("Total Cost").findNext().getColumn();

  var range = 
    sheet.getRange(2,idCol,sheet.getLastRow()-1,tcCol-idCol+1)
    .getA1Notation();

  var index = [];
  index[0] = hcCol - idCol + 1;
  index[1] = tcCol - idCol + 1;
  index[2] = range;

  return index;
}
```

I guess this question has two solutions: either I find a method that sets absolute reference, or someone tells me why my code is so slow. I'm new to this stuff and have a lot of room for improvement. Let me know any suggestions you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem with speed lies in here

```
for(i=0;i<compSht.getLastRow()-1;i++) {
    aEquation[i] = new Array;    

    aEquation[i][0] =
      "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(" + compSht.getRange(i+2, idCol).getA1Notation() 
      + ",'" + arcStr + " Submission'!" + vIndex[2] + "," + vIndex[0] + 
      ',false), "No Data")';
  }
  compSht.getRange(2, hcCol, lRow-1).setValues(aEquation);
}
```

More specifically 
`compSht.getRange(i+2, idCol).getA1Notation()`

Essentially what's happening is that you're getting a range from the sheet every time that loop iterates, which slows things down drastically. A better solution would be to get the range of the whole sheet (or however large the range you're working in is), and use `var values = compSht.getRange(desiredRange).getValues()` to get a 2D array of all the values of the cells (including empty cells).

You could then modify the values array as necessary, then copy it back to the range as such
 `compSht.getRange(desiredRange).setValues(values);`

Just remember to change where you're looking in the values array to account for the array index starting at 0 instead of 1.

As far as getting the A1 Notation goes in that case, this is a little sloppy but you could create an array to refer to like

**Okay everything works now**

```
var alpharray = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];
var doubleAlpha = [];
var fullArray = [];
var k = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < 26; i++){
  for(var j = 0; j < 26; j++){
    doubleAlpha[k] =  `${alpharray[i]}` + `${alpharray[j]}`;
    fullArray[i] = alpharray[i];
    k++;
  }
}
for(var k = 26; k < 26 + doubleAlpha.length; k++){
  fullArray[k] = doubleAlpha[k-26];
}
```

That will give you an array with all columns up to ZZ, then you could just attach the row number to the column's letters and you'll have your A1 notation. So for your case if you're looking at row i+2 and column idCol, you could get the A1 notation by doing

```
var string = "";
string += fullArray[idCol-1] + (i+2);
```

So if `idCol` is 49 and `i` is 5, then `string` will output AW7.

Hope this helps

Edit: If you want to also just save time with those for loops, I generated an array full of the combinations if you just want to copy it:

```
var columnArray = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","AA","AB","AC","AD","AE","AF","AG","AH","AI","AJ","AK","AL","AM","AN","AO","AP","AQ","AR","AS","AT","AU","AV","AW","AX","AY","AZ","BA","BB","BC","BD","BE","BF","BG","BH","BI","BJ","BK","BL","BM","BN","BO","BP","BQ","BR","BS","BT","BU","BV","BW","BX","BY","BZ","CA","CB","CC","CD","CE","CF","CG","CH","CI","CJ","CK","CL","CM","CN","CO","CP","CQ","CR","CS","CT","CU","CV","CW","CX","CY","CZ","DA","DB","DC","DD","DE","DF","DG","DH","DI","DJ","DK","DL","DM","DN","DO","DP","DQ","DR","DS","DT","DU","DV","DW","DX","DY","DZ","EA","EB","EC","ED","EE","EF","EG","EH","EI","EJ","EK","EL","EM","EN","EO","EP","EQ","ER","ES","ET","EU","EV","EW","EX","EY","EZ","FA","FB","FC","FD","FE","FF","FG","FH","FI","FJ","FK","FL","FM","FN","FO","FP","FQ","FR","FS","FT","FU","FV","FW","FX","FY","FZ","GA","GB","GC","GD","GE","GF","GG","GH","GI","GJ","GK","GL","GM","GN","GO","GP","GQ","GR","GS","GT","GU","GV","GW","GX","GY","GZ","HA","HB","HC","HD","HE","HF","HG","HH","HI","HJ","HK","HL","HM","HN","HO","HP","HQ","HR","HS","HT","HU","HV","HW","HX","HY","HZ","IA","IB","IC","ID","IE","IF","IG","IH","II","IJ","IK","IL","IM","IN","IO","IP","IQ","IR","IS","IT","IU","IV","IW","IX","IY","IZ","JA","JB","JC","JD","JE","JF","JG","JH","JI","JJ","JK","JL","JM","JN","JO","JP","JQ","JR","JS","JT","JU","JV","JW","JX","JY","JZ","KA","KB","KC","KD","KE","KF","KG","KH","KI","KJ","KK","KL","KM","KN","KO","KP","KQ","KR","KS","KT","KU","KV","KW","KX","KY","KZ","LA","LB","LC","LD","LE","LF","LG","LH","LI","LJ","LK","LL","LM","LN","LO","LP","LQ","LR","LS","LT","LU","LV","LW","LX","LY","LZ","MA","MB","MC","MD","ME","MF","MG","MH","MI","MJ","MK","ML","MM","MN","MO","MP","MQ","MR","MS","MT","MU","MV","MW","MX","MY","MZ","NA","NB","NC","ND","NE","NF","NG","NH","NI","NJ","NK","NL","NM","NN","NO","NP","NQ","NR","NS","NT","NU","NV","NW","NX","NY","NZ","OA","OB","OC","OD","OE","OF","OG","OH","OI","OJ","OK","OL","OM","ON","OO","OP","OQ","OR","OS","OT","OU","OV","OW","OX","OY","OZ","PA","PB","PC","PD","PE","PF","PG","PH","PI","PJ","PK","PL","PM","PN","PO","PP","PQ","PR","PS","PT","PU","PV","PW","PX","PY","PZ","QA","QB","QC","QD","QE","QF","QG","QH","QI","QJ","QK","QL","QM","QN","QO","QP","QQ","QR","QS","QT","QU","QV","QW","QX","QY","QZ","RA","RB","RC","RD","RE","RF","RG","RH","RI","RJ","RK","RL","RM","RN","RO","RP","RQ","RR","RS","RT","RU","RV","RW","RX","RY","RZ","SA","SB","SC","SD","SE","SF","SG","SH","SI","SJ","SK","SL","SM","SN","SO","SP","SQ","SR","SS","ST","SU","SV","SW","SX","SY","SZ","TA","TB","TC","TD","TE","TF","TG","TH","TI","TJ","TK","TL","TM","TN","TO","TP","TQ","TR","TS","TT","TU","TV","TW","TX","TY","TZ","UA","UB","UC","UD","UE","UF","UG","UH","UI","UJ","UK","UL","UM","UN","UO","UP","UQ","UR","US","UT","UU","UV","UW","UX","UY","UZ","VA","VB","VC","VD","VE","VF","VG","VH","VI","VJ","VK","VL","VM","VN","VO","VP","VQ","VR","VS","VT","VU","VV","VW","VX","VY","VZ","WA","WB","WC","WD","WE","WF","WG","WH","WI","WJ","WK","WL","WM","WN","WO","WP","WQ","WR","WS","WT","WU","WV","WW","WX","WY","WZ","XA","XB","XC","XD","XE","XF","XG","XH","XI","XJ","XK","XL","XM","XN","XO","XP","XQ","XR","XS","XT","XU","XV","XW","XX","XY","XZ","YA","YB","YC","YD","YE","YF","YG","YH","YI","YJ","YK","YL","YM","YN","YO","YP","YQ","YR","YS","YT","YU","YV","YW","YX","YY","YZ","ZA","ZB","ZC","ZD","ZE","ZF","ZG","ZH","ZI","ZJ","ZK","ZL","ZM","ZN","ZO","ZP","ZQ","ZR","ZS","ZT","ZU","ZV","ZW","ZX","ZY","ZZ"]
```

Comment: Wow! This is great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a general solution for creating absolute A1Notation references**

Expanding on the answer by @Passer-By (all credit to him). Here is a function that takes a row and column index and converts it to an absolute reference. Note: the empty string at the start of the array is not a typo, it is used to offset the index value of each letter by one.

```
const getAbsoluteA1Notation = (row, column) => {
var columnLetters = ["", "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","AA","AB","AC","AD","AE","AF","AG","AH","AI","AJ","AK","AL","AM","AN","AO","AP","AQ","AR","AS","AT","AU","AV","AW","AX","AY","AZ","BA","BB","BC","BD","BE","BF","BG","BH","BI","BJ","BK","BL","BM","BN","BO","BP","BQ","BR","BS","BT","BU","BV","BW","BX","BY","BZ","CA","CB","CC","CD","CE","CF","CG","CH","CI","CJ","CK","CL","CM","CN","CO","CP","CQ","CR","CS","CT","CU","CV","CW","CX","CY","CZ","DA","DB","DC","DD","DE","DF","DG","DH","DI","DJ","DK","DL","DM","DN","DO","DP","DQ","DR","DS","DT","DU","DV","DW","DX","DY","DZ","EA","EB","EC","ED","EE","EF","EG","EH","EI","EJ","EK","EL","EM","EN","EO","EP","EQ","ER","ES","ET","EU","EV","EW","EX","EY","EZ","FA","FB","FC","FD","FE","FF","FG","FH","FI","FJ","FK","FL","FM","FN","FO","FP","FQ","FR","FS","FT","FU","FV","FW","FX","FY","FZ","GA","GB","GC","GD","GE","GF","GG","GH","GI","GJ","GK","GL","GM","GN","GO","GP","GQ","GR","GS","GT","GU","GV","GW","GX","GY","GZ","HA","HB","HC","HD","HE","HF","HG","HH","HI","HJ","HK","HL","HM","HN","HO","HP","HQ","HR","HS","HT","HU","HV","HW","HX","HY","HZ","IA","IB","IC","ID","IE","IF","IG","IH","II","IJ","IK","IL","IM","IN","IO","IP","IQ","IR","IS","IT","IU","IV","IW","IX","IY","IZ","JA","JB","JC","JD","JE","JF","JG","JH","JI","JJ","JK","JL","JM","JN","JO","JP","JQ","JR","JS","JT","JU","JV","JW","JX","JY","JZ","KA","KB","KC","KD","KE","KF","KG","KH","KI","KJ","KK","KL","KM","KN","KO","KP","KQ","KR","KS","KT","KU","KV","KW","KX","KY","KZ","LA","LB","LC","LD","LE","LF","LG","LH","LI","LJ","LK","LL","LM","LN","LO","LP","LQ","LR","LS","LT","LU","LV","LW","LX","LY","LZ","MA","MB","MC","MD","ME","MF","MG","MH","MI","MJ","MK","ML","MM","MN","MO","MP","MQ","MR","MS","MT","MU","MV","MW","MX","MY","MZ","NA","NB","NC","ND","NE","NF","NG","NH","NI","NJ","NK","NL","NM","NN","NO","NP","NQ","NR","NS","NT","NU","NV","NW","NX","NY","NZ","OA","OB","OC","OD","OE","OF","OG","OH","OI","OJ","OK","OL","OM","ON","OO","OP","OQ","OR","OS","OT","OU","OV","OW","OX","OY","OZ","PA","PB","PC","PD","PE","PF","PG","PH","PI","PJ","PK","PL","PM","PN","PO","PP","PQ","PR","PS","PT","PU","PV","PW","PX","PY","PZ","QA","QB","QC","QD","QE","QF","QG","QH","QI","QJ","QK","QL","QM","QN","QO","QP","QQ","QR","QS","QT","QU","QV","QW","QX","QY","QZ","RA","RB","RC","RD","RE","RF","RG","RH","RI","RJ","RK","RL","RM","RN","RO","RP","RQ","RR","RS","RT","RU","RV","RW","RX","RY","RZ","SA","SB","SC","SD","SE","SF","SG","SH","SI","SJ","SK","SL","SM","SN","SO","SP","SQ","SR","SS","ST","SU","SV","SW","SX","SY","SZ","TA","TB","TC","TD","TE","TF","TG","TH","TI","TJ","TK","TL","TM","TN","TO","TP","TQ","TR","TS","TT","TU","TV","TW","TX","TY","TZ","UA","UB","UC","UD","UE","UF","UG","UH","UI","UJ","UK","UL","UM","UN","UO","UP","UQ","UR","US","UT","UU","UV","UW","UX","UY","UZ","VA","VB","VC","VD","VE","VF","VG","VH","VI","VJ","VK","VL","VM","VN","VO","VP","VQ","VR","VS","VT","VU","VV","VW","VX","VY","VZ","WA","WB","WC","WD","WE","WF","WG","WH","WI","WJ","WK","WL","WM","WN","WO","WP","WQ","WR","WS","WT","WU","WV","WW","WX","WY","WZ","XA","XB","XC","XD","XE","XF","XG","XH","XI","XJ","XK","XL","XM","XN","XO","XP","XQ","XR","XS","XT","XU","XV","XW","XX","XY","XZ","YA","YB","YC","YD","YE","YF","YG","YH","YI","YJ","YK","YL","YM","YN","YO","YP","YQ","YR","YS","YT","YU","YV","YW","YX","YY","YZ","ZA","ZB","ZC","ZD","ZE","ZF","ZG","ZH","ZI","ZJ","ZK","ZL","ZM","ZN","ZO","ZP","ZQ","ZR","ZS","ZT","ZU","ZV","ZW","ZX","ZY","ZZ"];
  return `$${columnLetters[column]}$${row}`;
};
```

Keywords:
getA1Notation
absolute cell reference google sheets
fixed cell reference google sheets
locked cell reference google sheets
dollar signs

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but thought I'd leave this here for others searching for a solution to this issue.
Expanding further on the previous answers.
I solved it with "one row" with this

```
inputString.replace(/([a-zA-Z])(?=\d)/, '$$$1$');
```

So first I create a string containing the A1 Notation that I want to become static, run it through this replace that is checking for the first letter and the first number and then inserts a $ before each. And then inserting that string in the

Answer (score 0):

```
inputString.replace(/([a-zA-Z])(?=\d)/g, '$$$1$');
```

To fit the case of a range bigger than one cell.

I couldn't make it a comment on {I Have No Idea What I am Doing} answer